# How to wire light switch replacement - lots of wires in wall box

Tags: electrical, receptacle

In my bedroom light switch I have 3 sets of cable coming into the box. 1 from the ceiling fan.  1 from the last working receptacle and going to the next outlet.

- From the last working receptacle is white, black and green.
- From the ceiling fan is white, black and green.
- Going to the next outlet is white, black green and red.

I don't know how to wire it. It seems like I've tried every different combination but obviously I haven't.

Do I use a Single pole switch?

Currently, the light switch is controlling every single thing on the circuit after the switch. Which is 3 outlets in that bedroom.1 bathroom light, 1 closet light and and entire guest bedroom (1 light and 4 outlets).

[image: hand-drawn sketch of wiring in question]

Comment: Probably the idea is that a switch *in this box* should control one or more *but not all* of the further receptacles.   The black should carry always on hot and the red should carry switched hot.  It sounds like your main problem is in the next downstream box where the red is feeding everything and the black is not used.  How you fix that depends on what you want.  What would you like to be switched?  And, does the black/red cable continue past the next box?  (Or perhaps the problem is you have only connected switched hot downstream?)

Comment: What is the switch supposed to control??

Answer (score 0):

All neutral/white wires together.

All ground/green and/or bare wires together.

Black - previous receptacle (incoming hot) + next receptacle (outgoing hot) + a short additional black wire together.

The other end of the short black wire goes to one screw on the switch.

The black wire going to the light goes to the other screw on the switch.

The red wire was previously used to provide a switched receptacle. Assuming you want the switch to *only* control the fan and not control the receptacle, cap the red wire here and in the receptacle connect two short black wires to the black wire and connect one to each screw on the hot side of the receptacle, and cap the red wire there as well.

Comment: What about the red wire going to the next receptacle?

Comment: Oops. Didn't notice that. That makes me wonder if there is already a switch somewhere. Was the pervious light or fan switched? Or is this totally new?

Comment: Actually, I have a hunch that red was previously for a half switched receptacle. Check the first ongoing receptacle. It should have that red wire. Is it connected or capped with a wire nut?

Comment: From the breaker box, it starts at an outlet and then goes to two 3-way switches in the hallway and then to this particular light switch. The red wire is in the romex that comes out of this particular light switch to the next out let.

Comment: I added a picture to the original post to clarify.

Comment: Open up the receptacle that is presumed to be at the other end of the red wire. Tell us the status of the red wire there.

Comment: It is screwed into the plug.

Comment: Then it is probably one side has a white wire and the other side has red and black. Take a look at the sides. On the neutral (white wire) side there should be a metal tab that connects the two screws. On the hot (black and red) side, is that tab there or missing?

Comment: Pictures of the actual switch and outlet boxes, with the wires still connected, but the devices pulled out so the connections can be seen (done with breaker off, of course) would be most helpful. They show more than you may know to put on a diagram...

Comment: Tab is not missing on the hot side.

Comment: Red and black both connected to same side of receptacle?

Comment: No. 2 blacks on one side. 1 red on the other.

Comment: Holy moly! There should *never* be a black on the neutral side. Something is very rotten in Denmark. Should be two whites in the box - are they simply connected to each other but not to the receptacle?